# Vertical scrollbar displaces table rows HTML

Tags: html, css

I am working with a table design that should have its height and width full-expandable.

The table works great, but I cannot adjust or fit the column names position over the table columns due the scrollbars width. When the scrollbar is visible (and it should be always visible) the table rows are being displaced and their columns names looks bad.

Can you please give me some thoughts?

Is there any way to change the scrollbar z-index or something that avoids the displacing behavior?

Here is a jsFiddle: [See sample here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gabriel_Mendez/T2pmq/)

HTML:

```
     <div id="tablecontainer">
        <div id="topbar">
            <div class="colname cellwidth1">ABC</div>
            <div class="colname cellwidth2">ABC</div>
            <div class="colname cellwidth3">ABC</div>
            <div class="colname cellwidth4">ABC</div>
        </div>
        <div class="breakline"></div>
        <div id="expandtable">
            <div class="divrow">
                <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>
            <div class="divrow">
                <div class="divcell cellwidth1">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="divcell cellwidth2">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="divcell cellwidth3">&nbsp;</div>
                <div class="divcell cellwidth4">&nbsp;</div>
            </div>          
        </div>
        <div class="breakline"></div>
        <div id="topbar">
            <div class="colname cellwidth1">ABC</div>
            <div class="colname cellwidth2">ABC</div>
            <div class="colname cellwidth3">ABC</div>
            <div class="colname cellwidth4">ABC</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, #expandtable, #tablecontainer 
{
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

#tablecontainer 
{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 50px;
    max-width: 900px;
}

#expandtable
{
    margin: 5px 0 0 0px;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 60%;
    border-bottom: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.breakline { clear:both;}

.divcell 
{ 
    float:left; 
    border: 1px solid #999; 
    box-sizing: border-box; 
    min-height: 30px; 
}
.colname 
{ 
    float:left; 
    border: 1px solid #e5e5e5; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cellwidth1 { width:10%; }
.cellwidth2 { width:45%; }
.cellwidth3 { width:35%; }
.cellwidth4 { width:10%; }
```

Comment: Why aren't you using a `<table>`?

Comment: 9 upvotes for reinventing the wheel?

Comment: Since you always want/will have a scrollbar: #topbar {margin-right:17px}

Answer (score 1):

If you want more control over the scrollbar, you can use a jQuery plugin such as this: http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/

However, before you even start with that you should read up on the proper use of `<table>`

Instructions for this can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Answer (score 1):

Well it works in Chrome on Mac (at least it's a start. Scrollbar hovers over content instead of displacing it).

With what you have, it might not be possible to factor this change in with just CSS. You might have to use Javascript to find the width of the columns below the header, then adjust the column header's widths accordingly.